# Why is the official Ubuntu website only in English, when Ubuntu strives for being a multilingual OS?

Tags: language-support, ubuntu-website

For Canonical/Ubuntu it is important to provide their software in as many languages as possible.

Then, why doesn't Canonical offer an official website in different languages?
(As far as I know the official website www.ubuntu.com is only in English).

Comment: I have found this LoCo page: http://loco.ubuntu.com/teams/ubuntu-de-locoteam/ .

Comment: This is a good question. Perhaps the LoCo pages should be accessible right from the main Ubuntu.com somehow.

Answer (score 6):

The official website is in English. If you want it in your own language you can go to the local group (or LoCo). Here is a list: http://www.ubuntu.com/support/community/local-language

Ubuntu website in ...

- Dutch: http://www.ubuntu-nl.org/
- French: http://www.ubuntu-fr.org/
- Japanese: http://www.ubuntulinux.jp/

These are also community driven so not official Canonical websites (though they are supported/acknowledged/endorsed on the official site).

---

Ubuntu official (I mean made and managed directly by Canonical) forums/websites always start with `ubuntu-` and ends with `org` except (very) few exceptions. They do not do one page by language but by country.

Comment: And for German support the best website is ubunterusers.de? Isn't it? thx in advance

Comment: Does not look like Germany has a website on the loco page so the answer might be: No ;)

Comment: @aski Ubuntu official (I mean made and managed directly by Canonical) forums/websites always start with `ubuntu-` and ends with `.org` except (very) few exceptions. They don't do one page by "language" but by country.

Comment: As I  remember ubuntuusers.de is no loco page, but a community driven.

Comment: @ braiam: Then, waht is the offical Germany page, created by canonical?

Comment: @Rinzwind *"except (very) few exceptions"* I always add exceptions! D:<

Comment: I understand NOTHING, but doesnt matter!!! :(

Comment: @aski according to [this](http://loco.ubuntu.com/teams/) there is [kubuntu-de.org](http://loco.ubuntu.com/teams/kubuntu-de.org/)

Answer (score 0):

This question is entirely inappropriate for this board. If you have a problem with Canonical's business decisions, you should contact them directly. Anything else would be speculation.

Most of the software that Canonical provides is FOSS and not written by them. If it happens to be available in multiple languages, it's because a lot of people put in time, effort, and money to do so, and are offering it to the community.